# Wrong request.body obtained (value and name are misplaced) after making a request

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I'm beginner at coding since some months and I'm stuck on a problem that I can't solve:

In my angular application I'm making a post request (the followUser):

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http'
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UsersService {

  constructor(private http : HttpClient) { }


  getAllUsers() : Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/chatApp/users')
  }
  followUser(userFollowed) : Observable<any> {
  console.log(userFollowed);
  return this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/chatApp/follow-user', {
    userFollowed
  });
  }
}
```

with userFollowed being an object containing an ID ( the console.log returns 5da24df09a3e662fd437d21b)

and however when I receive this object in my node backend and I simply console.log it like this:

```js
followUser (req,res) {
   console.log(req.body);}
```

I obtain this from the console :

`{ '{"userFollowed":"5da24df09a3e662fd437d21b"}': '' }`

Also as you can see this is a mess and I don't know how to fix it (I can't access my userFollowed value)

EDIT : followed user is a simple object, as I said in the comment section when I console.log(request.body) in my front I obtain the value I expected:

`{userFollowed:"5da24df09a3e662fd437d21b"}`  and when I get it in my backend and I console.log(request.body) I obtain `{  '{"userFollowed":"5da24df09a3e662fd437d21b"}': '' }`

EDIT 2 : I'm putting my whole code which concern userFollowed below:

```
<div class = "container" style = "margin-top : 30px">
  <div  class = "row"> 
    <div class = "col s12 m4 13">
      
     </div>
  
     <div class = "col s12 m8 19">
       <div class = "rox">
         <div class = "col s 12 m6  14 cardDiv" *ngFor = "let user of users">
          <div class = "card">
            <a>
              <div class = "card-image imgDiv">
                <img  class = "imgCircle responsive-img" src = "http://placehold.it/100x100">
              </div>
            </a>
            <div class = "card-action">
              <h3 class = "card-title">
                  {{user.username}}
                  ici sont les username normalement :/
              </h3>
              <p>country</p>

              <button class = "btn" (click)= "followUser(user)">follow</button>
               <!--" need to add this instead of /chat solo-->
              <a class = "secondary-content" [routerLink] = "['/chat', user.username]">
                <i clas = "material-icons">chat</i>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

and the TS file linked with it :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {UsersService} from './../../services/users.service';
import _ from 'lodash';
import {AuthenticationService } from '../../services/authentication.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-people',
  templateUrl: './people.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./people.component.scss'],
})
export class PeopleComponent implements OnInit {
users = [];
loggedInUser : any;
  constructor( private usersService : UsersService, private authService : AuthenticationService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loggedInUser = this.authService.userData;
    this.getUsers();
    }
  
getUsers () {
  this.usersService.getAllUsers().subscribe (data =>{
    _.remove(data.result, {username : this.loggedInUser.username});
    this.users=data.result;
    console.log(this.users);
});
}
followUser(user) {
  console.log(user._id);
this.usersService.followUser(user._id).subscribe(data=> {
  console.log(data);
})

}
}
```

EDIT 3 : my node looks like this :

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const logger = require('morgan');
const methodOverride = require('method-override')
const cors = require('cors');
const mysql = require('mysql');
// Token handling : 
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const config = require('./config/config');
//disk storage :
const multer = require('multer');
// password hashing : 
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const saltRounds = 10;
const dateTime = require ('date-time');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
// ---------------------------------------
const connection = mysql.createConnection({          // a placer dans une variable environnementale

});


var app = express();
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(methodOverride());
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// TUTO PATRICK MONGODB

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const dbConfig = require ('./config/secret');
const message = require ('./routes/messageRoutes');
const auth = require ('./routes/authRoutes');
const users = require('./routes/userRoutes');
const friends = require ('./routes/friendsRoutes');

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect(
    dbConfig.url,
    { useNewUrlParser : true}
);
app.use ('/chatApp', auth);
app.use('/chatApp', message );
app.use('/chatApp', users);
app.use('/chatApp', friends);

app.use(express.json());
```

then the route:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const friendCtrl = require('../controllers/friends.js');
const authHelper = require("../helpers/authHelper");

router.post('/follow-user', authHelper.ProtectedRoutes, friendCtrl.followUser);
module.exports = router;
```

then the code that is executed

```
var User = require('../Models/userModels');
module.exports = {
    followUser (req,res) {
        console.log(req.body);};
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201969/discussion-on-question-by-aurelien-c-wrong-request-body-obtained-value-and-name).

Answer (score 0):

So thanks for those who tried to help, what happened is my HTTP interceptor was setting a header twice (application/json and application/ x-www-form-urlencoded), causing bodyparserJson and bodyparserUrlencoded to both parse my request wich resulted in this really weird result.
The wrong code interceptor :

```
import {
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpResponse,
  HttpErrorResponse
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError, from } from 'rxjs';
import { ToastController } from '@ionic/angular';
import {Storage} from '@ionic/storage';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import {AuthenticationService} from './../services/authentication.service';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TokenInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {



  constructor(public toastController: ToastController, private storage : Storage) {}


  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) : Observable<HttpEvent<any>>{
    const TOKEN_KEY ='ACCES_TOKEN';    
    console.log("requete avant",request.body);
     return from(this.storage.get(TOKEN_KEY))
          .pipe(
            switchMap(token => {
              if (token){
              console.log("InterceptedHTTPRequest")
               const headers = request.headers
                        .set('x-access-token', token)
                        .append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); // application/json instead of application/x-www..., had to use the 2nd one because of CORS blocked in chrome
               const requestClone = request.clone({
                 headers 
                });
                console.log("request interceptée et clonée");
                console.log("request apres",requestClone.body);
              return next.handle(requestClone);
              }
              else {
                return next.handle(request);
              }

              }),
            );

  }
}
```

the corrected interceptor :

```
import {
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpResponse,
  HttpErrorResponse
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError, from } from 'rxjs';
import { ToastController } from '@ionic/angular';
import {Storage} from '@ionic/storage';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import {AuthenticationService} from './../services/authentication.service';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TokenInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {



  constructor(public toastController: ToastController, private storage : Storage) {}


  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) : Observable<HttpEvent<any>>{
    const TOKEN_KEY ='ACCES_TOKEN';    
    console.log("requete avant",request.body);
     return from(this.storage.get(TOKEN_KEY))
          .pipe(
            switchMap(token => {
              if (token){
              console.log("InterceptedHTTPRequest")
               const headers = request.headers
                        .append('x-access-token', token)
               const requestClone = request.clone({
                 headers 
                });
                console.log("request interceptée et clonée");
                console.log("request apres",requestClone.body);
              return next.handle(requestClone);
              }
              else {
                return next.handle(request);
              }

              }),
            );

  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could share the code that was wrong and how you corrected this. Thank you